# How to pass parameters between pages in HTMLHELP (.CHM files)

Tags: javascript, parameters, chm

I need to create a Windows help file where there are many topics which are very similar, just differing in detail. Instead of creating a page for every combination (about 40 per topic!), I want to use Javascript to modify the detail, but I need to pass parameters to each page.

I tried to use the URL search argument:

```
<a href="page.htm?argument">Page</a>
```

This works nicely in standard HTML files in a browser, even in the HTML Help Workshop, but as soon as it is compiled in a .CHM file, I get an error page stating: This page can’t be displayed.

I tried to put "page.htm?argument" in the .HHP but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Some information for you adding e.g. .css or .js file to the [FILES] section like described below.

The help compiler tries to pull into the .chm all local files that are *directly* referenced in the HTML files, whether they be other HTML files, graphics, cascading style sheets, etc. Make sure your script file and CSS is compiled into your CHM too.

To make extra certain that all graphics (and Cascading Style Sheets like *.css) are compiled into the .chm, you can list them in the [FILES] section of your project (.hhp) file. With HTML Help Workshop, the procedure is as follows:

1) Open the project file in HTML Help Workshop.

2) Click the Add/Remove Topic Files button on the Project tab.

3) Click Add.

4) In the File Name field, type *.gif (or *.jpg).

5) Click Open, and then select e.g. the graphics files to add.

If you want, you can use wildcards in the [FILES] section to specify every file in a given directory. For example:

[FILES] 
html*.htm 
images*.gif 
css\foobar.css

Of course, you'd have to edit the project file in a text editor such as Notepad to do this and compile again. Note that all files must be on the project file "folder level" or in subfolder structure level.

Comment: The problem is not that "page.htm" can't be found in the CHM, but that "page.htm?search" can't be found. Here are the results when I right-click on the page and select "Properties", showing the URL(good): mk:@MSITStore:C:\Winet\WinetHelp.chm::/html/page.htm
(bad): res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm#mk:@MSITStore:C:\Winet\WinetHelp.chm::/html/page.htm?search

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the window.name property. Passing two parameters:

```
<script>window.name = "p1=Par1;p2=Par2";</script>
<a="href=page.htm>Goto page</a>
```

In page.htm:

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function getName(c_name) {
    var c_start,c_end;
    if (window.name.length > 0) {
        c_start = window.name.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = window.name.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) c_end = window.name.length;
            return unescape(window.name.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<H2 id="h2id"></H2>
<script>
document.getElementById("h2id").innerHTML = 'P1: '+getName("p1")+ ' P2: '+getName("p2");
</script>
</body>
```